# postPersist get called infinite times Symfony2

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I want to create logs for who deleted, created, updated, etc. a document for each of my documents in my project so that I can track in the future who did what for a particular document (table) in the application.

I have create the following service:

**NameSpace/BundleName/Resource/Config/services.xml**

```
 <service id="edu.account.event.listener1" class="Namespace\BundleName\EventListener\postPersistListener">
        <argument type="service" id="session"/>
        <argument type="service" id="router"/>
        <tag name="doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener" event = "postPersist" method="postPersist"/>
 </service>
```

My Listener is:

```
class postPersistListener
{
    private $session;
    private $router;
    private $commonFunctions;
    private $constants;

    public function __construct(Session $session, Router $router)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();
        $this->constants = new allConstants();
    }

//Always fire when any Add/Update/Delete operations will occurs in any documents in account module
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->createLog($args);
    }

    public function createLog(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $userID = $this->session->get('userid');
        $event = "CREATED";
        $document = $eventArgs->getDocument()->getId();
        $this->dm = $eventArgs->getDocumentManager();
        $md = $this->dm->getClassMetadata(get_class($eventArgs->getDocument()));
        $documentName = $md->getcollection();

        $this->commonFunctions->createActivityLog($this->dm, $document, $documentName, $event, $userID);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And the function `createActivityLog()` is defined in another file as:

```
public function createActivityLog($dm, $documentId, $documentName, $event, $userId)
{
    $systemIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $computerName = gethostbyaddr($systemIp);

    $documentActivity = new ActivityLogs();

    $documentActivity->setDocumentName($documentName);
    $documentActivity->setEvent($event);
    $documentActivity->setObjectId($documentId);
    $documentActivity->setOnDate(time());
    $documentActivity->setUserId($userId);
    $documentActivity->setComputerIp($systemIp);
    $documentActivity->setHostName($computerName);
    $dm->persist($documentActivity);
    $dm->flush();
}
```

So now when I am creating documents it gets executed infinite times. It inserts around 30000 entries in Document: "ActivityLogs". Instead it should insert one entry into "ActivityLogs" Log table.

Comment: Try commenting out the $dm->flush(); in your createActivityLog method.

Flushing while still working "in" the postPersist, as this event is called in EntityManager#flush(), possible leads to the event being called over and over.

Comment: can you please explain I did not get this?.  I already commented this Line:
$dm->flush();

Comment: it does not save any, entries going to save in "ActivityLogs" document if I comment
$dm->flush(); in createActivityLog function.

Comment: @SunilRawat You are persisting when you are in Post persist, this will trigger another post persist :) This is example of infinite loop :D

Comment: then where to precisest, can you please guide me..